# Iterate over json with inspec and only target specific entries for tests

Tags: ruby, devops, chef-infra, inspec

To test if the correct consul version is installed on my servers, I am trying to write an inspec test. The idea is to call this test with mutiple ip addresses, parse it against json (which I get from the consul api) and then check the consul version for only the servers that I have the IPs listed for.

Now I am struggling with iterating over the json and then only checking the correct servers.

It should look something like this:

```
describe json(content: http('http://172.17.0.1:8500/v1/agent/members').body) do

for i in 0..2 do
 ip_addresses.each { |node| its ([i, 'Tags', 'build']) { should match consul_version }.where(['Addr'] == node) }
end
```

It doesn't work of course, but I think it explains what I am trying to achieve.

Is there an approach that would allow me to do this?

Edit:
The json boils down to this:

```
[
{
    "Addr": "192.100.100.100”,
    "Name": “machine0”,
    "Tags": {
        "build": "1.11.3",
    }
},
{
    "Addr": "192.100.100.101”,
    "Name": “machine1",
    "Tags": {
        "build": "1.11.3”,
    }
},
{
    "Addr": "192.100.100.102”,
    "Name": “machine2”,
    "Tags": {
        "build": "1.11.3",
    }
}
]
```

Comment: maybe you can tell what is the expected input format .. or maybe a sample?

Comment: Of course, it boils down to this really: [
    {
        "Addr": "192.100.100.100”,
        "Name": “machine0”,
        "Tags": {
            "build": "1.11.3",
        }
    },
    {
        "Addr": "192.100.100.101”,
        "Name": “machine1,

        "Tags": {

            "build": "1.11.3”,

        }

    },

    {
        "Addr": "192.100.100.102”,
        "Name": “machine2”,
        "Tags": {

            "build": "1.11.3",

        }

    }

]

Comment: Please update such details in the question, it will be far more readable.